# How to map Integer List from result

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am using java 7 and jdbc template to query a integer array from postgresql.My code is as below:

```
 @Autowired
 private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemp;

 String SQL = "select item_list from public.items where item_id=1";
 List<Integer> ListOfitems=jdbcTemp.queryForList(SQL , Integer.class);
```

My item_list  column is integer[] in postgresql.But when I try like thid it throws an error as **Bad value for type int psql exception**.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: what is the type of `item_list` in your SQL-Statment. Is it a List of Integers? Then you should change the resultType from `List<Integer>` to `List<List<Integer>>`

Comment: item_list is an integer array in postgres

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [java.sql.Array](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/array.html).

If you want to get only integer array you can try like this

```
String SQL = "select item_list from public.items where item_id=1";
Array l = template.queryForObject(SQL, Array.class);
List<Integer> list = Arrays.asList((Integer[]) l.getArray());
```

Or use RowMapper

```
Foo foo = template.queryForObject(SQL, new RowMapper<Foo>(){
        @Override
        public Foo mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) throws SQLException {
            Foo foo = new Foo();
            foo.setName(rs.getString("name"));
            foo.setIntegers(Arrays.asList((Integer[]) rs.getArray("item_list").getArray()));
            return foo;
        }
    });
```

Class Foo:

```
class Foo {
    private String name;
    private List<Integer> integers;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

queryForList saves each row that you got as a result from your query as an element of a List. It doesn't take the list that is saved into a column and returns it for you.

From the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#queryForList-java.lang.String-java.lang.Class-) : "The results will be mapped to a List (one entry for each **row**) of result objects, each of them matching the specified element type."

At best you will get a `List<List<Integer>>` returned, but I'm not sure fi you can use `List<Interger>.class` as a parameter for the call.